# AngularJs Filter : how to bind two values in one span,where one value is using filter?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

I am new to angularJS.

I want an output like this using angularJs Filter

My first expression: 456 $5.00

If i didn't use the filter then,{{}} displays correctly,but if use filter the output shows as below:

```
{{ 456+ " " + 56 | currency}}
```

My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app>
<p>My first expression: {{ 456 + " " + 5  | currency}}</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Any suggestions please.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand. What do you want to achoeve. What is your input, and what is the desired output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use parentheses: `{{ 456 + " " + (5  | currency) }}`.

Or just move 456 out of the expression: `456 {{ 5 | currency }}`.